# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers C#

Tags: c#

I tried to solve projecteuler 4th project with C# but I don't receive the correct answer, I get 90909. Can someone spot my mistake?

The problem goes like this:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

```
namespace Largest_palindrome_product{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);                
            return new string(charArray);
        }


        int result = 0;
        string rev= "hello";
        string palindrome = "hello";
        string bingo = "hello";
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i< 1000; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y< 1000; y++)
            {
                result = i * y;
                bingo = result.ToString();
                rev = Reverse(bingo);
                j = int.Parse(bingo);
            }

            if (rev == bingo)
            {
                palindrome = bingo;
            }
        }
        Console.Write(palindrome);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're checking rev and bingo outside the inner loop.

Comment: I take it you're turning it into a string to easily reverse it? I'd keep it as an int and just compare the ints.

Comment: Why don't you try starting you loops at the MAX value and substract 1 each iteration. This way the first coincidence will be the maximum palindrome, not the first one. Also the `if` should be inside the inner loop as stated by @John.

Comment: Ops, yep my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what has caused so much confusion is the use of `String` this just complicates thing having to convert them back and forth.

Your program works fine (if the `if` is moved as per John's comment) if only you'd checked the new number was larger!

here is my take on it:

```
// stolen from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-digits-integer-overflow-handled/
int Reverse(int num)
{
    int rev_num = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        rev_num = rev_num * 10 + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return rev_num;
}


int result = 0;
int palindrome = 0;
int j = 1;
for (int i = 999; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int y = 999; y > 0; y--)
    {
        result = i * y;
        if (result == Reverse(result))
        {
            if (result > palindrome)
            {
                palindrome = result;
            }
        }  
    }
}
Console.Write(palindrome);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Before the second for-loop, you could add the following statement:

    `if (i*999 <= palindrome) break;`

You cannot find a greater palindrome in that case, so you can stop immediately.

Comment: Nice call creating a decrescent loop

Comment: @KevinKouketsu it was  r1verside's idea! Also think you meant `decrement` not `decrescent `?

Comment: @Matt I'm sorry, i'm Brazilian so you know... i`m always trying to write better. Thanks for the advice